# How can I call a function with onClick with my inline buttons with Svelte?

Tags: function, button, onclick, inline, svelte

The buttons load into their correct column and I am trying to add functionality to them. Just adding the onClick to the first button to call my function saveMe() and I get the error saveMe is not defined. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried several things to get this to work. hrefs, getElementById, and even a simple alert in the button, but nothing works or I get errors.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
import { beforeUpdate, createEventDispatcher, onMount, shared } from 'svelte';
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { produce } from 'immer';
//import {saveMe} from './newlocal.js';
//console.log('saveme', saveMe);
//alert({saveMe})
//const testmsg = newlocal.saveMe(test);
let buttons = '<div class="btn-group style="width:100%"><button style="width:33.3%" type="button" onClick="saveMe()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></button style="width:33.3%"><button style="width:33.3%"><i class="fa fa-rebel"></i></button><button style="width:33.3%"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button></div>';

export let faketable = [{Color:'BLUE', Car:'Camaro', Brand:'Chevy', Action:buttons, ID: 1},
{Color:'RED', Car:'Pinto', Brand:'Ford', Action:buttons, ID: 2},
{Color:'Gray', Car:'Gremlin', Brand:'Chevy', Action:buttons, ID: 3},
{Color:'White', Car:'Maverick', Brand:'Ford', Action:buttons, ID: 4},
{Color:'Yellow', Car:'Beetle', Brand:'Volkswagen', Action:buttons, ID: 5},
{Color:'Black', Car:'Batmobile', Brand:'Wayne Enterprises', Action:buttons, ID: 6},
{Color:'Pewter', Car:'Silverado', Brand:'Chevy', Action:buttons, ID: 7},
{Color:'Yucky', Car:'F-150', Brand:'Ford', Action:buttons, ID: 8},
{Color:'Navy Blue', Car:'911', Brand:'Porsche', Action:buttons,ID: 9},
{Color:'Cherry Red', Car:'Diablo', Brand:'Lamborghini', Action:buttons, ID: 10},
{Color:'Black', Car:'Sporster', Brand:'Harley Davidson', Action:buttons, ID: 11},
{Color:'Orange', Car:'Viper', Brand:'Dodge', Action:buttons, ID: 12}                
];

export let len = faketable.length;
console.log("len", len)

export let columns = ["Color", "Car", "Brand", "Action"];

export let apagetable = [];

export let clickable = true

export let currentPerPage = 10;
export let perPageOptions = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
export let currentPage = 1;
export let defaultpage = 1;

export let exactSearch = false; 

export let newpages = parseInt(len / currentPerPage);
console.log('newpages', newpages)

export let sortType = 'asc';

let tr;

export let x;
export let z;

const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

export function click(row) {
    console.log('click', row);
        if (!clickable) {
            return;
        }
        if (getSelection().toString()) {
            // Return if some text is selected instead of firing the row-click event.
            return;
        }
        dispatch('row-click', row);
}

document.getElementById("saveme");
console.log('document', document);
function saveMe(){
    console.log('saveme');
    alert('I have been saved!');
}

export function sort(index) {
        if (index > -1) {
            setSortIcon(index);
            getPaged({colName: columns[index].field, direction: sortType});             
        }
}   

onMount(() => {
    calcPage(defaultpage);
});

$: selectedPage = selected + 1;

export function calcPage(defaultpage){
    x = parseInt(len / currentPerPage); 
    z = len % currentPerPage;
    apagetable = [];
    var temptable = [];
    var i = 0;  
    if (len > currentPerPage){
        if (z != 0){
            x += 1;
    }
    }

    for (i = 0 + (currentPerPage * (defaultpage - 1)); i < currentPerPage * defaultpage; ){
        if (!faketable[i]){
            break;
        }
        temptable.push(faketable[i]);   
        i++;
    }
    apagetable = temptable;
    return apagetable;
}

function getNext(){
    defaultpage += 1;
    if (defaultpage >= x){
        defaultpage = x;
    }
    calcPage(defaultpage);
}

function getPrev(){
    defaultpage -= 1;
    if (defaultpage <= 0){
        defaultpage = 1;
    }
    calcPage(defaultpage);
}

function getPageAmount(){   
    currentPerPage = perPageOptions;
    calcPage(defaultpage); 
    perPageOptions = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]; 
}

</script>

<div>
        <table ref="table" class="table" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>                    
                    {#each columns as column, x}    
                    <th style="width: { column.width ? column.width : 'auto' }" align="center"> 
                    {column}
                    </th>                       
                    {/each}                 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {#each apagetable as row}       
                <tr class="{ clickable ? 'clickable' : '' }" on:click="{() => click(row)}">
                    {#each columns as column, x}
                    <td align="center">                 
                        {@html row[column]}
                    </td> 
                    {/each}                 
                </tr>
                {/each}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <button style="right;"><i class="material-icons" on:click="{getPrev}">chevron_left</i></button><button style="float: right;"><i class="material-icons" on:click="{getNext}">chevron_right</i></button> 
    <div class="table-footer">
        <div class="datatable-length">
            <label>
                <span>Rows per page:</span>
                <select bind:value="{perPageOptions}" on:change="{getPageAmount}">      
                    {#each perPageOptions as option} 
                        <option value={option}>  
                        {option}
                        </option>
                    {/each}
                </select>               
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="datatable-info">
            {(currentPage - 1) * currentPerPage ? (currentPage - 1) * currentPerPage : 1}
                - {currentPerPage} of {len} 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<style> 

    tr.clickable {
        cursor: pointer;
    }   

    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    } 

  table tr td {
        padding: 0 0 0;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        border-bottom: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;        
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: center;     
    }   

    table th {
    border-radius: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    table tbody tr:hover {
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
</style>
```

I'm just trying to get bare-bones functionality so I can add more specific details to the buttons as I go. But for this example, once the save button is clicked, I want an alert saying 'I have been saved!'.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 approaches to handling clicks in Svelte:

1. Inline (with anonymous arrow function):

```
    <script>
      let selectedTabIndex = 0;
    </script>
    
    <li class:is-active={selectedTabIndex === 0}>
      <a href="#" on:click={() => (selectedTabIndex = 0)}>Tab 1</a>
```

2. With a function:

```
<script>

  let hidden = false;
  
  // with "old style" function
  function toggleSectionVisiblity(event) {
    hidden = !hidden;
  }

  // or with arrow function
  const toggleSectionVisiblity = (event) => {
    hidden = !hidden;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" on:click={toggleSectionVisiblity}>Show / hide</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but these examples won't work for what I am trying to do. My markup is in a string and I format it using @html. I have tried this before and I get errors or no response at all.

Comment: @j_w_d To be compiled into working html and javascript, I believe the on:click idioms need to be present from the start, not inside a string rendered as html.

Comment: @j_w_d what you are trying to do might be impossible since Svelte needs to parse the markup to convert it to JavaScript functions which updated DOM so that reactivity works.

Comment: I think both of you are probably right, unless there's an update that let's us do this; it's just not doable right now. I can get it to work with an 'iframe' but there is limited functionality with 'iframe' to do what I want. If someone figures it out, that would be awesome, but for now I will have to try something else. Thanks!